# Intellij documentation popup hides warning popup

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, popup, settings, hidden

In the Intellij Settings I activated `Editor > General > Show quick documentation on mouse move` and I like it. But when there is a warning message also shown as popup when the mouse hovers over, then the documentation popup just hides the warning like this:

[image]
Well, that's not nice. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: The real solution here seems to be for IntelliJ to coalesce these two pieces of information into the same pop-up window, stacked one over the other, as e.g. vscode does. I'm in the same boat as you.

Answer (score 1):

The are a couple of alternatives to displaying the quick documentation as a popup:

- Display the quick documentation in a separate panel.
- Display the quick documentation in a floating window.

To display the quick documentation in a separate panel:

- Position the mouse so that the quick documentation popup is displayed.
- Click the Options icon in the bottom right of the popup.
- Select **Open as a Tool Window** from the drop down menu.

[image: popup1]

After doing that the quick documentation popup is displayed in a panel on the right. It is still automatically updated as you move the mouse.

[image: popup2]

Alternatively, to display the quick documentation as a floating window:

- Click the **Options** icon in the top right corner of the panel.
- Select **Windowed Mode** from the drop down menu.

[image: popup3]

After doing that the quick documentation is shown as a floating window which you can position wherever you want. You could even place it on another screen if you have multiple screens. Again the content is still automatically updated as you move the mouse.

[image: popup4]

Select **Open as a Popup** from the Options drop down menu on the panel or the floating window (or press CTL/Q) to revert to using a popup for the quick documentation.

The best choice is a matter of personal taste, but both of those approaches would solve your overlapping popups problem.

---

**Update:**
The previous screen shots were produced using IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 EAP. With Ultimate 2017.3 it seems that the situation is slightly different. After clicking the Options icon, only a control to adjust the font is shown. In that case click the Pin icon in the top right of the window:

[image: popup5]

After doing that click the Options icon in the top right of the window to see the menu options:

[image: popup6]

Comment: I have no futher space on my screen. These two alternatives don't improve the situation. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm, and somehow I have no options "Open as a Tool Window" or Docking Mode or Split Mode for the Quick Documentation.

Comment: @Arceus I have just updated my post. I was using IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 EAP but it looks like things are slightly different with earlier versions. Do the new screen shots help?

Comment: Ok, I only have the Community Edition but it looks the same as in your update screenshot. Floating and Windowed Mode are the only possibilities here.